# Issues with Application Scope for fetching the CFC's

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to get the CFC linked but i am getting an error:

Here is my Configration in my Application.cfc

```
<cfset Application.relativePath = "/">
  <cfset Application.componentsPath = Replace(Application.relativePath,"/","",'All')>
  <cfset Application.cfcpath = Application.componentsPath & "com">
  <cfset Application.tools = '#Application.cfcpath#.tools'>
```

Now when i acces the cfc from my page like this:

```
<cfset result = Application.cfcpath.tools.saveDrivers(form)>
```

I am getting an Error:

```
Element CFCPATH.TOOLS is undefined in a Java object of type class [Ljava.lang.String; referenced as ''
```

if i try

```
<cfset result = Application.tools.saveDrivers(form)>
```

I get an Error:

```
The saveDrivers method was not found.
Either there are no methods with the specified method name and argument types or the saveDrivers method is overloaded with argument types that ColdFusion cannot decipher reliably. ColdFusion found 0 methods that match the provided arguments. If this is a Java object and you verified that the method exists, use the javacast function to reduce ambiguity.
```

I dumped out the Application Scope and all seems ok, but i am not sure what is troubling here

Answer (score 9):

Both `Application.cfcpath` and `Application.tools` are just strings, so can only be used as strings; whereas `Application.cfcpath.tools` within the statement:

```
<cfset result = Application.cfcpath.tools.saveDrivers(form)>
```

is a variable reference. You can't have a string holding a variable reference and hope that somehow ColdFusion will magically equate the two.

It's unclear from your question whether you are trying to create an object with your statement, or are simply referencing an existing one. I suspect it's the former. In which case, you want this sort of thing, I think:

```
tools = createObject(Application.tools);
```

Comment: Typed out the same thing. Just beat me! As adam has said you have set strings not objects and there is no `saveDrivers()` method for a string.

Comment: I tried this and It worked too: `<cfset this.mappings["/com"] = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()) & "com/">` and then doing it like this: `<cfset Application.tools = new com.tools()>`

Comment: OK, so you understand how all this works and you've sorted your problem out now?